# Windows Service stops on Server Patch

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-services, patch

I'm a developer that has a Windows Service that runs on a production server that sends emails that are entered into a database on a database server. Although the service is set to start automatically, whenever the web server gets patched (which happens every other week), for some reason the service fails to start and various emails don't get sent.

I don't actually have access to the server, so I have to request a build administrator to start the service. What I want to know is whether there is any reason for the service to fail to start when the server is patched?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime if any errors occur in your service , the service is automatically terminated. Specifically, any `NULL` exceptions affects the running of the service. You can g=debug your service to determine whether any such exceptions occur.

Another reason is if you used any threads, it is possible to have a thread sleep for an extended time period, such as 2 weeks. You should also check your code to ensure that this isn't the case :)